# Three.js won't render my scene without a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently making a small simple randomly generated maze game, and it was working fine last session. All of the sudden when I resumed work on it trying to integrate OBJ loading, my scene would no longer render. I tried removing literally everything I did before it broke, and now I have this odd bug where unless I have a ReferenceError in my code it won't render at all.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MazeGamer 2.0</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon.png">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/glcode.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mazeGen.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Tree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scene.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/keyPress.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/input.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; background-color: black; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var width = 3;
        var height = 3;


        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        document.body.addEventListener("keydown",keypress_calls);
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener("click", on_click);
        window.addEventListener("resize",resizeWindow);

        var web_scene = new SCENE(scene,camera,renderer,width,height);
        scene = web_scene.setup();

//            var billboard;
//            for(var i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i++)
//            { 
//                if(scene.children[i].name === "billboard")
//                { 
//                    billboard = scene.children[i]; 
//                } 
//            }

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            billboard.rotation.y = camera.rotation.y; //this line is the one that determines whether my scene renders or not and I have no idea why
            gamePadInput();
        };

        render();
    </script>
</body>
```

As you can see, the commented line should be a ReferenceError since the variable that its using an uninstantiated variable, which is:

```
index.html:52 Uncaught ReferenceError: billboard is not defined
```

When I comment out the line though, and have no errors reported in my console, my scene is entirely blank. I'm honestly baffled and flustered beyond reason by why this is happening. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT #1

```
//the following is in the file input.js

var buttonList = {};
var gamepad;

function gamePadInput(){    
    if(gamepad === undefined){
        gamepad = navigator.getGamepads()[0];
    }
    if(navigator.getGamepads()[0] !== undefined){
        buttonList.a = gamepad.buttons[0].pressed;
        buttonList.b = gamepad.buttons[1].pressed;
        buttonList.x = gamepad.buttons[2].pressed;
        buttonList.y = gamepad.buttons[3].pressed;
        buttonList.rb = gamepad.buttons[5].pressed;
        buttonList.lb = gamepad.buttons[4].pressed;
        buttonList.rt = gamepad.buttons[7];
        buttonList.lt = gamepad.buttons[6];
        buttonList.l3 = gamepad.buttons[10].pressed;
        buttonList.r3 = gamepad.buttons[11].pressed;
        buttonList.u = gamepad.buttons[12].pressed;
        buttonList.d = gamepad.buttons[13].pressed;
        buttonList.l = gamepad.buttons[14].pressed;
        buttonList.r = gamepad.buttons[15].pressed;
        buttonList.sel = gamepad.buttons[8].pressed;
        buttonList.strt = gamepad.buttons[9].pressed;
        buttonList.lxAxis = (Math.abs(gamepad.axes[0]) <= 0.25) ? 0 : gamepad.axes[0];
        buttonList.lyAxis = (Math.abs(gamepad.axes[1]) <= 0.25) ? 0 : gamepad.axes[1];
        buttonList.rxAxis = (Math.abs(gamepad.axes[2]) <= 0.20) ? 0 : gamepad.axes[2];
        buttonList.ryAxis = (Math.abs(gamepad.axes[3]) <= 0.20) ? 0 : gamepad.axes[3];
    }

    if(buttonList.rxAxis !== 0)
    {
        camera.rotation.y += (buttonList.rxAxis * -0.0625);
    }
    if(buttonList.lxAxis !== 0)
    {
        camera.translateX(buttonList.lxAxis * 0.0625);
    }
    if(buttonList.lyAxis !== 0)
    {
        camera.translateZ(buttonList.lyAxis * 0.0625);
    }
    if(buttonList.d){
        console.log("reset");
    }
    return buttonList;
};
```

Comment: The error is exactly as it says. You haven't defined billboard at all as a variable

Comment: what's in gamePadInput? can you comment out that line?

Comment: @Nick, I edited the post to show you what gamePadInput is, but it basically polls the computer for any external gamePads like a 360 controller or something similar. For some reason things do render when that is commented out.

Comment: @Rush2112 I understand that the variable isn't defined, but when it is defined the scene doesn't render.

Comment: What is the code for `navigator`? Maybe start over: come up with the shortest, simplest possible reproduction of the problem and post that, pasting *ALL* of the JS code you've written.

Comment: @kristina the navigator code is a built in Web API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getGamepads